# SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: ":":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, pg-search

I'm having trouble running pg_search. I think it's set up correctly, but for some reason when trying to run a search, this comes up:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: ":": SELECT "courses".*, ((ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple',
coalesce("courses"."title"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'finance' || ' ''')), 0))) AS
pg_search_rank FROM "courses"  WHERE (((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("courses"."title"::text, '')))
@@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'finance' || ' ''')))) ORDER BY pg_search_rank DESC, "courses"."id" ASC
```

Course model:

```
include PgSearch
scope :by_course_title, lambda { |ttl|
  _by_course_title(ttl) if ttl.present? }
pg_search_scope :_by_course_title, against: :title
```

Search Controller:

```
def index
    @course = Course.by_course_title(params[:fname])
end
```

In the html:

```
<% @course.each do |courses| %>
    <div><%= courses %></div>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible that this is caused by the .each? If I only keep <%= @course %>, the page loads up and shows:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x....>
```

Am I supposed to convert the resulting array before passing the .each function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a PostgreSQL specific library (`PgSearch`) and you're using SQLite3 as your database.  Pick one or the other, but not both.

The casting operator `::` in `coalesce("courses"."title"::text, '')` is valid for PostgreSQL only.  With SQLite you can leave out casting completely (the `::text` part), but as mentioned before, you likely won't get `PgSearch` to work correctly unless you switch over to a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Oh I see. Well I ended up learning basic SQL and juste created my own search code. I'm still very new to this and thought that SQLite and PostgreSQL were somehow connected.

Comment: They are both relational database systems supporting ANSI SQL (for the most part) - and that is about the extent of their relationship.  Please mark as accepted if this helped you.